# Angular 10 division on scss color variable

Tags: angular, sass

I am rebuilding an Angular 7 app with Angular 10.

In the previous version, I used this following for some hover color adjustments on links:

**variables.scss**

```
$mycolor: #050505;
```

**app.component.scss**

```
@import '~assets/scss/variables.scss';
a {
    color: $mycolor;
    &:hover {
        color: $mycolor / 1.1;
    }
    &:active {
        color: $mycolor * 1.3;
    }
}
```

This approach no longer seems to work, as I receive `SassError: Undefined operation "#050505 / 1.1".`  How can I implement basic math functions with SCSS variables in Angular 10?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ;)

Just wrap your calculations in "#{ //calculation }" this madness.

```
$mycolor: #2196f3;

a {
    color: $mycolor;
    &:hover {
        color: #{$mycolor / 1.1};
    }
    &:active {
        color: #{$mycolor * 1.3};
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a {
  color: #2196f3;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1e88dd;
}
a:active {
  color: #2bc3ff;
}
```

I used to forget this all the time, can be hella frustrating.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to work. Just started migrating this today hoping for it to go reasonably quick and here I am a couple hours later and stuck working on bugs as well as `ng serve` no longer reloading after file changes. Maybe this is a sign I need just abandon using Angular.

Comment: @pspahn. Haha, maybe. Here just for you to double check https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/rNemVRG

Answer (score 0):

Seems there were breaking changes with a new version of SASS and this now requires using the `sass:color` module.

```
@use 'sass:color';
&:hover {
    color: color.adjust($mycolor, $lightness: -10%);
}
```